# Current Date and time format in StructField with type as TimestampType

Tags: python, datetime, pyspark, casting, aws-glue

Trying to create a dataframe with one of the fields to be a timestamp (current timestamp in the format of %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S  using `date.today()`). I have tried multiple ways but it just seems to not take any. 
I create data as a list pre-hand and pass it on to CreateDataFrame
When starttime is set as datetime format

```
data_for_frame = [{'program': 'SomeProg', 'operation': 'SomeOperation', 'hostname': 'test-hostname', 'starttime': datetime.date(2020, 4, 9), 'endtime': '2020-04-09 06:01:34'

schema_frame = StructType(List(StructField(program,StringType,true),StructField(operation,StringType,true),StructField(marketplace,StringType,true),StructField(hostname,StringType,true),StructField(starttime,TimestampType,true),StructField(endtime,TimestampType,true)))

dynamic_frame = sparkSession.createDataFrame(data_frame, schema_frame)
```

And when starttime is set as string format

```
data_for_frame = [{'program': 'SomeProg', 'operation': 'SomeOperation', 'hostname': 'test-hostname', 'starttime': '2020-04-09 06:01:34', 'endtime': '2020-04-09 06:01:34'

schema_frame = StructType(List(StructField(program,StringType,true),StructField(operation,StringType,true),StructField(marketplace,StringType,true),StructField(hostname,StringType,true),StructField(starttime,TimestampType,true),StructField(endtime,TimestampType,true)))
```

When I pass data to it as datetime format `date.today()` it fails with

```
TypeError: field starttime: TimestampType can not accept object datetime.date(2020, 4, 9) in type <class 'datetime.date'>
```

**as float**

```
time.time()
```

**As string**

```
time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',time.localtime(time.time()))
```

**As string**

```
now = datetime.now()
date_time = now.strftime("%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

**fails with**

```
TypeError: field starttime: TimestampType can not accept object '2020-04-09 06:01:34' in type <class 'str'>
```

Comment: Can you include a [mcve]? I am not able to reproduce the errors your are describing, so perhaps I'm doing it a different way? Show the whole code used to create the dataframe from that example data you provided. This is how I did it: `df = spark.createDataFrame([Row(**d) for d in data])` where `data` is the list of dictionaries you provided.

Comment: @pault Question updated, Date_frame is created with 
```
for index in range(len(schema_from_glue)):
        if ((schema_from_glue[index]['Type']) == "string"):
            data_dict[schema_from_glue[index]['Name']] = randomString()
        elif ((schema_from_glue[index]['Type']) == "timestamp"):
            data_dict[schema_from_glue[index]['Name']] = date.today()```
 or
 ```date.today()``` was replaced with ```time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',time.localtime(time.time()))``` for string format